# Using Jquery, which <a> tag was clicked

Tags: jquery, click, anchor, mixpanel

I am trying to use jQuery to find the Text of the link that was clicked. Below is the code snippet.

```
 <li><a id="PAYROLL" href="../PayrollAdmin/Payroll_Default.aspx"><span>PAYROLL</span> </a> </li>


 <li> <a id="WELFARE" href="../HRAdmin/Welfare_Default.aspx"><span>WELFARE</span></a> </li>
```

This is my jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("a").click(function () {
 var LinkText= $(this).text();
   alert(LinkText);
});
</script>
```

NB: i donot want to use onclick event listener to track this. Help

EDIT
Now here is the real thing i want achieve. I am trying to track my site using mixpanel, but each time i use this code, it dosen't track.

//Mixedpanel sdk loaded above already

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function (e) {


 mixpanel.track_links(this.id, this.id +" was clicked", {
        "referrer": document.referrer
    });

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't abuse `alert` as a debug tool.

Comment: Is the script included after the HTML, If not you need to encase your script inside DOM ready handler.

Comment: When clicking an anchor you're generally redirected to another page, and when that happens all javascript from the previous page is lost. The question then is, do you want to redirect the user to another page, or do you want to get the text and stay on the current page.

Comment: If you don't want to use an onclick event, why did you tag this `click`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your code needs to be in a document ready handler or it may not run, depending on your scripts being at the top or the bottom of the page. Then you can do this -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        alert(this.id); // because your id and text match
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you jay it worked out of the box. wish i had enough points to vote you up.

Comment: If you like this answer you can always accept it :-)

Answer (score 1):

use document [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventdefault()
        var LinkText= $(this).text();
        alert(LinkText);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
$("a").click(function(event){         //bind an event listener to all links on the page
    event.preventDefault();      //prevent the default action (a redirect) from occurring
    console.log($(this).text()); //log the text from the clicked link
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/U75n3/)

Comment: `event` is undefined ;)

Comment: @MaiKaY It seems to work in the fiddle without running `event` through `function()`